# Swiper.js navigation buttons disappear in production mode

Tags: next.js, swiper.js

**Swiper.js navigation buttons disappear in production mode**

Swiper.Js navigation button showing in the development but does not show in the production.

**next.config.js**

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS(withSass({
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 100000
        }
      }
    });

    return config;
  }
}));
```

**_app.js**

```
import 'swiper/swiper.scss';
import 'swiper/css/swiper.css';
import 'swiper/components/navigation/navigation.scss';
import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss';
import 'swiper/components/scrollbar/scrollbar.scss';
import 'swiper/components/effect-cube/effect-cube.scss';
```

**My Component**

```
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Scrollbar, A11y]);

 <Swiper  
          threshold="50"
          navigation
          style={{ width: '100%', height: '98%', }}
          scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
          initialSlide={sliderIndex}    
        >
          <SwiperSlide className={classes.slider}>
            {createPages(0, 8, 0)}
          </SwiperSlide>

          <SwiperSlide className={classes.slider}>
            {createPages(8, 16, 1)}
          </SwiperSlide>

</Swiper>
```

Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move import styles from _App.js to your main scss file.

```
import 'swiper/swiper.scss';
import 'swiper/css/swiper.css';
import 'swiper/components/navigation/navigation.scss';
import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss';
import 'swiper/components/scrollbar/scrollbar.scss';
import 'swiper/components/effect-cube/effect-cube.scss';
```

It's seems in production mode it didn't attach swiper modules scss.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which was: when I was changing the size of the screen, I was losing my custom pagination and navigation buttons, and when I was refreshing the page, I was having them back. I solved my problem as follows:

1. Wrapped my Swiper with `<div className="slider-wrapper">`
2. I made new elements for the pagination and navigation:

```
<div className="prev">
<div className="next">
<div className="pagination">
```

Their definition in the swiper is as follows:

```
pagination={{ el: ".pagination", clickable: true }}
navigation={{
  prevEl: ".prev",
  nextEl: ".next",
}}
```

In addition, I have put all my elements (Swiper, pagination, and navigation) inside `<div className="slider-wrapper">`